# Get the keycode of a key, from a custom made keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I'm trying to transform a Minitel to a computer with a Raspberry Pi.

This is a minitel:

[image]

So I soldered the matrix of the minitel keyboard to a usb keyboard pcb, like this:
 [image]

Everything is working ok, I recieve some keys from my custom keyboard. I just need to remap the keys appropriately.

So I'm trying to create a program that will ask me to press `a` and trap the corresponding keycode, and then with all keys of my custom keyboard, to finaly produce a xmodmap file.

The only problem I have is that I can't figure out on how can I get that keycode (and only that!). I tried `xev` but there's too much data displayed to filter it out.

I know I could track all the keycodes by hand, but I'll transform 10 Minitels, so I would prefer a quicker way!

Comment: Could you dump the ROM(s) from Minitel(s) you have, for the MESS project?  That hardware is currently undumped and is certainly of historical importance.

Comment: why not, but I've got no idea on how to do that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're trying to do this in shell or similar (else, you'd just use the X libraries directly). If so, you may find `xinput --test «device-name»` much easier to parse.

Unfortunately, it really isn't shell-scripting friendly. But you can make it work with `stdbuf`. It runs until you kill it, but your shell script could pipe it to `read`.

So, you can do something like this:

```shell
stty -echo
stdbuf -oL xinput test 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard' \
    | perl -nE 'BEGIN {$| = 1} m/^key press\s+(\d+)/ and say $1' \
    | for key in q w e r t y; do
         echo -n "Please press $key: "
         read -r keycode
         echo "key $key = $keycode"
    done
stty echo
```

You will need to use the correct keyboard name in place of "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard". You can find it with `xinput list`:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Unfortunately, you have to use a specific device—you can't use the core keyboard.

(Also, you'll need to find a way to kill the xinput in the above, or just content yourself to hit Control-C when you've entered all the keys. And you'll probably want to list more keys than qwerty.)

Comment: thanks derobert! that fits perfectly my need! I used the `id` of the keyboard instead of its name, because I had conflicts with 2 same names. So `xinput test 18` where 18 is the id of my keyboard.

Comment: if I could do the same with a command that is not long running (i.e. stops after the first key pressed and returns the key code) it would be a kind of dream :)

Comment: @xavier.seignard I tried and couldn't find a utility that does that. But it'd be fairly easy to take the xinput source and make it work that way... check `test.c`, looks like the relevant function is `print_events`. Maybe xorg would take a patch to add a flag to stop after *n* events?

Comment: @xavier.seignard I just ran across a way to sort of do that... `xinput --query-state` gives the current state, and exits immediately. You could busy-loop it.