# The n key doesn't work anymore but N does

Tags: x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout, key-mapping

I've been playing around `xmodmap` to create a custom keyboard (refer to [Get the keycode of a key, from a custom made keyboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81030/get-the-keycode-of-a-key-from-a-custom-made-keyboard) also).

But now, I can't use the <kbd>N</kbd> key anymore, but the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> still works fine.

I think I messed up something, so I performed a reset to defaults of my keyboard (using the Ubuntu system settings).

Now everything seems to work ok, **except** my <kbd>N</kbd> key, my <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> key works.

How can I get that key working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that was some `.xbindkeysrc` file that messed up all that. I removed it, and it's ok now.

Answer (score 2):

First, check that you've restored the keyboard layout properly. `echo keycode 57 = n N | xmodmap -` should do the trick (adjust the keycode if you aren't using a PC keyboard — run `xev` to see the keycode sent by the key).

If pressing the key does nothing visible even in xev, there is probably an application that has grabbed the key, i.e. claims the key as a shortcut. If your X server isn't too old, you can [see a list of active grabs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/manipulating-x-key-and-pointer-grabs-on-the-command-line/62254#62254) with the command

```
xdotool key XF86LogGrabInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo rm /var/lib/xkb/*.xkm` This clears a sort of cache of keyboard layouts. I had similar problems in the past when using custom keyboard layauts and this solved the issue.